# Swift: weird behavior of assertionFailure in release build

Tags: ios, swift

In my opinion, `assertionFailure` will be ignored in release build. But when I run codes below in release mode, `assertionFailure` can run and stop the program. Why?

*Codes*

```
enum MessageType: RawRepresentable {
    case news
    case unknownMessageType(value: String)

    init?(rawValue: String) {
        assertionFailure("Tihs assertionFailure will never stop execution")
        switch rawValue {
        case "A":
            self = .news
        case "B":
            self = .news
        case "C":
            self = .news
        case "D":
            self = .news
        case "E":
            self = .news
        case "F":
            self = .news
        case "G":
            self = .news
        case "H":
            self = .news
        case "I":
            self = .news
        case "J":
            self = .news
        case "K":
            self = .news
        case "L":
            self = .news
        case "M":
            self = .news
        case "N":
            self = .news
        case "O":
            self = .news
        case "P":
            self = .news
        case "Q":
            self = .news
        case "R":
            self = .news
        case "S":
            self = .news
        case "T":
            self = .news
        case "U":
            self = .news
        default:
            assertionFailure("This assertionFailure will cause a fatal error and stop execution")
            self = .unknownMessageType(value: rawValue)
        }
    }

    var rawValue: String {
        switch self {
        case .news:
            return "A"
        case .unknownMessageType(value: let value):
            return value
        }
    }
}
```

**this statement will cause a crash**
`let message = MessageType(rawValue: "aaaa")`, caused by the second `assertionFailure` , not the first one.

**Another weird thing is** if I remove any two `case`(at least two `case`) in function `init?(rawValue: String)`, assertionFailure will be ignored, there will not be any crash.
PS, I do not disable optimization for release build.

Edit on 2018-11-29

I posted a thread on [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/111158), it seems like a compiler bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted a thread on [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/111158), it seems like a compiler bug.